# 12 Buttons programmatically - How to handle each click

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a custom LinearLayout View that generates 12 Buttons. I would like to be able to handle each click event of them. Here's my cusom LinearLayout class:

```
public class SolutionButtons extends LinearLayout {

private static int AMOUNT_BUTTONS = 6;
private static int SIZE_BUTTONS = 130;
private static int PADDING = 13;

private ArrayList<Button> buttons;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public SolutionButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}
public SolutionButtons(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}
public SolutionButtons(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ArrayList<Button> getButtons() {
    return buttons;
}

public void init() {

    buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        ll.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        for(int j = 0; j < AMOUNT_BUTTONS; j++) {
            Button b = new Button(getContext());
            LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(SIZE_BUTTONS, SIZE_BUTTONS);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, PADDING, PADDING);
            b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.solution_button_background));
            buttons.add(b);
            ll.addView(b);
        }
        addView(ll);
    }
}
}
```

I want to be able to change the visibility of each button to GONE when pressed. I've tried it by implementing an onClickListener in the for-loop the buttons got created in, but it didn't work out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add  "tag" which  can be anything that allow you to recognize a View from others. You retrieve its value with getTag().

Comment: So you have to GONE rest of 11 button ?

Comment: No, GONE to the pressed button

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to your class following this :

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
             switch(v.getId()) {
                 case R.id.but_arr_date:
                     break;
                 case R.id.but_arr_time:
                     break;
                 case R.id.but_update_arr:
                     break;
                 case R.id.but_fin_date:
                     break;
                 case R.id.but_fin_time:
                     break;
              }

    }
};
```

and add

```
yourBut.setOnClickListener(onClickListener) to each button
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this ..

```
        for(int a = 0; a < taxi_type_spin.size(); a++){

               final Button rowTextView;
               rowTextView = new Button(getApplicationContext());
               rowTextView.setText(taxi_type_spin.get(a).taxi_type);
               rowTextView.setTextSize(15);
               rowTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
               LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
               //rowTextView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);      
               packageButtons.add(rowTextView);
               rowTextView.setLayoutParams(lparam);
               rowTextView.setId(a); /// Set ID to button like this .. 
               final int b = a;
               // get value of clicked item over here .. 

               rowTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button btn = (Button)v;
                    String get_value = btn.getText().toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button name is : " + get_value + " AND ID IS : " + rowTextView.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

              // add the textview to the linearlayout
              myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
              setSelectedButtonColor(b);
              setSelectedButtonColor(0);
        }
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like**

```
buttons.setId(j);
```

and check like

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case 0:
            // So on
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public void init() {
   buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
   setOrientation(VERTICAL);
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
      ll.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
      for(int j = 0; j < AMOUNT_BUTTONS; j++) {
          Button b = new Button(getContext());
          LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(SIZE_BUTTONS, SIZE_BUTTONS);
          layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, PADDING, PADDING);
          b.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
          b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.solution_button_background));
          b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                 v.setVisibility(GONE);
              }
          });
          buttons.add(b);
          ll.addView(b);
       }
       addView(ll);
   }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, as I described in my question

Comment: As per you comment you said you wan to GONE pressed button so this code work for this perfectly and i try then let you know to try it.